# Choose which key is used for inputting special APL characters

Tags: keyboard, apl, dyalog

I'm on Linux, and I just started using Dyalog APL. However, I would like to use the Control key instead of the Super key to input special characters. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on your exact platform and so a full answer is too long to embed here. Is all explained in detail on [apl.wiki/Typing_glyphs_on_Linux](https://aplwiki.com/wiki/Typing_glyphs_on_Linux).